# How to get the fingerprint of an encrypted ssh private key in go?

Tags: go, ssh-keys

Is there a way to get the fingerprint of a passphrase protected ssh private key in go without knowing the passphrase?

I know it's possible using the openssh tools:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f identity -N passphrase
# ...
$ ssh-keygen -l -f identity.pub
4096 SHA256:ecFemcAlOhQyFk/HWfAnx14T+SGuQImMvmEt+T1DarM x@x (RSA)
$ ssh-keygen -l -f identity
4096 SHA256:ecFemcAlOhQyFk/HWfAnx14T+SGuQImMvmEt+T1DarM x@x (RSA)
```

In go (golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) the `ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)` returns a `PassPhraseMissingError` and a nil key, so I can't call `ssh.FingerprintSHA256(key.PublicKey())` on it.

I would like to do this because then I could check if the agent can handle that key so that I don't need to let it try every key known by the agent when connecting.

Comment: If you `strace` `ssh-keygen`, you'll see that in your case it performs `openat(2)` to open "identity", sees it's not a public key part, closes it and then peforms `openat(2)` on "identity.pub"—just guessing how the relevant bit of information is named. So, to answer your question, no, you cannot but `ssh-keygen` cannot either.

Comment: @kostix looks like that solves it then :(

Comment: Try renaming your "identity.pub" to "identity.pub_" and see what happens to be 100% sure ;-)

Comment: Yeah I tried that, breaks.

Comment: OK, so I hope you see that apparently the real problem you're experiencing is that the fingerprint is the property of the public part of the key. Anyway, given the fact SSH keys are used in asymmetric cryptography, having private key w/o its public counterpart is sort of useless/unusual, no?

Comment: @kostix, every private key necessarily includes the public information too. That's why all private key implementations can have a [Public() method](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto#PrivateKey). So no, it is not unusual (nor useless) to not retain the public key.